# How can I install the "sub" library for g++ compilation for Festvox?

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, festival

I'm trying to configure and make festvox, but when I attempt making it, g++ shows errors with things such as -fpermissive and how it cannot locate the library "sub". How can I get the library?
Here is a part of the logs:

```
making in src/vc/src/analysis ...
g++ -o analysis main.o analysis_sub.o -L../lib -lsub -lsp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsub
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[4]: *** [Makefile:65: analysis] Error 1
making in src/vc/src/extdim ...
g++ -o extdim main.o -L../lib -lsub -lsp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsub
```

I have already tried using apt-get to see if the library resides in the repo, but I can't be sure that any of them actually stop the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I instead got Festival through apt. I felt at first that it would outdated, but it seems to be as up to date on there as on the website.

```
sudo apt install festival
```